# How do I tell OS X that an arbitrary controller is a MIDI device?

Tags: midi

I own a [Novation Twitch](http://novationmusic.com/twitch), and Novation has released a "MIDI Programming guide". Tonight, I've been working on some Quartz Composer based visualizations, and naturally I wanted to add a component of customization based off some suitable hardware I already own (the Twitch). So, I plugged it in and started pressing buttons.

Applications used to monitor MIDI such as [MIDISpy](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/midispy/id432601430?mt=12) never list any events as occurring, and I realized also that the Twitch does not show up in the built-in Audio MIDI Setup app in OS X.

My current theory is that OS X does not think the Twitch is a MIDI controller, and something "special" has to happen before it will interact with it like one.

Does anyone know what that "special" thing is? There is no ability to add a MIDI device in Audio MIDI Setup, only add Aggregate Input or Multiple Output Devices based off the devices already listed.

Comment: Obvious question: you installed the drivers for it, correct?

Comment: note that their programmer's reference says pretty clearly that it is a midi control surface ( http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:0U5EME2dUwcJ:www.novationmusic.com/download/801/+novation+twitch+%22midi+control+surface%22&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESjyxJm3xvJOXrKn6DXEFsauwgLnL-uQT4WU4tEPWpI8i2xC8CDnJ8VbZrS50sQYqG-j5dUTd1koCqXse4rLUgSgK5d1mCYb8QKMlJ7foDipEs4ZgpwzxAczIJ8I2uD4xxA0WL5j&sig=AHIEtbQMaagW6VnZoXhM8z6aUyllf2hsyQ )

Comment: I was hoping to avoid installing anything, as I figured it would still work in basic midi mode without anything special. System Profiler/System Information does show it in the device list when plugged in, but I will nevertheless give that a shot. Sensible idea :).

Comment: There is a driver DMG on their support site. Looks to be the driver only without the cruft.

Comment: Nice find. It's too bad you didn't *answer* the question or I could have accepted it :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obvious question: you installed the drivers for it, correct?

There is a driver DMG on their support site. Looks to be the driver only without the cruft.

Comment: No. No I didn't install the drivers for it. What a rookie mistake. Thanks for pointing out that they ship the drivers alone. Probably not for any good reason, but I didn't want to install an entire DJ software package just to get it to work.